# Error while using Oracle JDBC driver to access an LDAP server

Tags: java, jdbc, ldap

I'm trying to use Oracle JDBC driver to for accessing LDAP server. But I am getting error while I run this. Error is No suitable driver found for given URL.

This is the server:

> myldap.dreams.com:389

Service is `myapp`
This is the context: `cn=OracleContext,dc=dreams,dc=db`

Server type is `OID`

**XML:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://myldap.dreams.com:389/myapp,cn=OracleContext,dc=dreams,dc=db
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
            ....
</bean>
```

Comment: This may be a simple question but... did you add the JDBC JAR into your classpath?

Comment: yes i did. When i change url to something else other than ldap then it works.

Comment: What is the Oracle version you're working with?

Comment: @Carlos I am working with Oracle 11g.

Comment: Ensure you're using the correct driver for the specific Oracle version and for the OS you're running 32/64 bit, etc.

Comment: @ManoDestra I checked that too. It's not working.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a JDBC driver to talk to an LDAP server?  This approach cannot possibly work.  If you have an LDAP server to talk to, use something like Spring LDAP.